# xdg-open without an option to "remember"

Tags: ubuntu

On a brand new Ubuntu 19.04, the latest chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) refuses to remember my selection. I'm trying to open a zoom URL, I'm getting the [Open xdg-open?] and just the action buttons without the checkbox to store my selection. I have removed ~/.config/google-chrome options in order to reset it but still same behavior

[image: "Remember my choice" is missing]

Comment: I have found out why it does that but I haven't found a solution. It's Google's stupidity I guess. They have disabled the checkbox to store your selection in version 77: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14193532?hl=en